# Problema ao importar projeto github com imagem netbeans

Tags: imagem, github, netbeans

Todo projeto que eu crio no netbeans aqui em casa e tento importar no trabalho ou no notebook que eu tenho aqui mesmo da problema (sempre em partes com imagens)

Um exemplo de codigo:
https://github.com/fyalhed/TestIMGimport

Erro que aparece lá no trabalho no netbeans:

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\leo\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\TestIMGimporte -Djavac.includes=testimgimport/Test.java -Dnb.internal.action.name=run.single -Drun.class=testimgimport.Test run-single
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\leo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TestIMGimporte\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\leo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TestIMGimporte\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: C:\Users\leo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TestIMGimporte\build\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\leo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TestIMGimporte\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Users\leo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TestIMGimporte\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\leo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TestIMGimporte\build\classes
compile-single:
run-single:           ==COMEÇO DO ERRO EM VERMELHO
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
    at testimgimport.Test.initComponents(Test.java:17)
    at testimgimport.Test.<init>(Test.java:6)
    at testimgimport.Test$1.run(Test.java:61)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)  FIM DO ERRO EM VERMELHO ==================
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Comment: Eu clonei seu repositório e compilei o código, rodou normalmente pra mim

Comment: Você conseguiu executar o código e tudo?
Eu clono, o código aparenta estar sem erros, mas quando eu tento executar o jframe printa esses erros...

Comment: Como você executou o código? Eu compilei e executei pela linha de comando, o erro pode estar na forma como você compila e executa

Comment: Ah sim, acho que compilando e executando pela linha de comando vai funcionar, porque o código lá do trabalho roda certo (não tem erros, alias não tem nada de mais no código, só executa uma label com uma imagem de fundo)...
Meu problema é no netbeans, quando eu dou clone e tento executar com o shift+f6 não roda, da esses erros, só funciona na máquina que eu criei...